Foundry script: balance mismatch of tx caller
Found a balance mismatch (between actual & shown) for the caller's address when used as vm.startBroadcast(caller) in foundry script:
You can reproduce the error using this foundry script:
contract CounterScript is Script {
    address private delegate;

    function setUp() public {
        uint256 privateKey = vm.envUint("DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY");
        delegate = vm.addr(privateKey);
    }

    function run() public {
        vm.startBroadcast(delegate);

        console2.log("Balance: ", delegate.balance);

        Counter counter = new Counter();

        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}

Now, if you run this command:
$ forge script ./script/Counter.s.sol:AutoBridgeScript --private-key $DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY --rpc-url $NOVA_RPC_URL

Balance:  4611686043903352722517363181

But, actually balance is:
$ cast balance 0xB751710Af8Ce68677aB960adB103060f38d09714 --rpc-url $NOVA_RPC_URL
25476025062017363181

So, where is the problem?

Remove --private-key flag to view the original balance.
Balance:  25476025062017363181

Actually, by default when the same caller is used with private key, foundry somehow adds more gas coin to the caller and thus the balance shows as inflated. Although it would fail in real network, if the caller doesn't have enough gas coin for the transaction.
